# Finding usage of qualified class names (as opposed to imports) in a java codebase

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, fully-qualified-naming

I am looking for a way to find usage of **qualified class names**:

```
com.company.TheClass theInstance = new com.company.TheClass();
```

as opposed to **imports**:

```
import com.company.TheClass;
TheClass theInstance = new TheClass();
```

Is there a maven plugin that would help me find all usages of qualified class names against a java codabase?

**edit**:

**Oleg** kindly suggested the following [link](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/rules/java/imports.html#UnnecessaryFullyQualifiedName). It is very useful.

However I am just wondering how I could spot all fully qualified class name usage and **not just "unnecessary" fully qualified name usage.**

Some developer might for instance have for instance used `private java.util.List list1;`  without the corresponding import statement.

This is not considered as unnecessary by pmd but **is not good practice if there is no disambiguation needed**....

Comment: Is your question about how to find these references in a project, or about why this exists?

Comment: Any chance you're using an IDE? For example, Eclipse has a file search facility that you provide the qualified name to and check only "*.java" files

Comment: How many estimated qualified class names usages are there? Would a simple shell script (find + grep) help?

Comment: Depending on the  acces you may not need to import anything, but  otherway  you need import , because tat is the java way http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: My question is to find these references in a given codebase. There is also a requirement that I don't depend upon an IDE but rather that I use a maven plugin.

Comment: Fore example using a utility like checkstyle or other...

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/rules/java/imports.html#UnnecessaryFullyQualifiedName?

Comment: Thanks Oleg: spot on!

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect a limitation of this rule...